# Is there a more elegant way to write logic for multiple checkboxes being checked other than multiple if statements?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a windows forms application that has 4 check boxes that can be checked at the same time. I want to check to see what boxes are checked and do specific logic based on which boxes are checked. The issue being that if I end up trying to write code to check each possible combination of the check boxes I would have to write a long list of if else statements, and that is without checking for if there is only one checked. Is there any more elegant way to check whether or not multiple check boxes are checked? or am I stuck using if-else logic?

```
//This is the type of code I am trying to avoid
//check all the conditions
//check1 is a check to add keys
//check2 is to create docs
//check3 is to create keys
//check4 is to reorder keys
//createKeys() creates keywords
//createDocs() creates documents
//addKeys() adds keywords
//reorderKeys reorders the keywords
if(check1 && check2 && check3 && check4){
    createKeys();
    createDocs();
    addKeys();
    reorderKeys();
}
else if(check1 && check2 && check3){
    createKeys();
    createDocs();
    addKeys();
}
else if(check1 && check2 && check4){
    createDocs();
    addKeys();
    reorderKeys();
}
else if(check1 && check2){
    createDocs();
    addKeys();
}
else if(check1){
    addKeys();
}
else if(check2 && check3 && check4){
    createKeys();
    createDocs();
    reorderKeys();
}
else if(check2 && check4){
    createDocs();
    reorderKeys();
}
else if(check2){
    createDocs();
}
else if(check3 && check4){
    createKeys();
    reorderKeys();
}
else if(check3){
    createKeys();
}
else if(check4){
    reorderKeys();
}
```

Code update to be more specific

Comment: Without more information about what "do something" means, there isn't enough to go on to provide good alternatives. If there are 16 different "do something" alternatives, then perhaps you can generalize the if-statements but you still need the 16 "do something" portions.

Comment: You could convert the 4 checkboxes to bit-values, combine them to a number from 0-15, and then use a switch-statement, but I am not sure it would become clearer.

Comment: It's hard to know.  This seems like an X-Y problem, because I bet there is a flaw in your "do something" logic that, once fixed, will simplify your problem with check boxes.

Comment: essentially each combination of the check boxes will need to do completely separate logic in their own order. I don't know how to simplify so many nested if statements. so for each if statement the do something will be different from each other I don't have the do something logic at the moment because I am looking for a way to simplify the structure rather than the logic inside

Comment: You're ignoring what we're telling you.  We need more context to help you solve your problem.  You need to tell us specifically what your logic is and what each check box means.  Calling them "check1" and so on is unhelpful as it doesn't lead us to understand what it is that your application is supposed to be doing.  The reason all this is necessary is because with context we might be able to identify a flaw in your *approach* rather than trying to address your current design which has resulted from a (possibly) flawed approach.

Comment: Nested conditional expression is a possibility but if you are looking for clarity then probably not the best option

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wfQTbA) will help you, idk. For example, this could work, but it can be overuse depending on your real problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to `if/else` would be a method table. You can create a dictionary and put all code as `Action`

```
var methodTable = new Dictionary<(bool, bool, bool, bool), Action>
{
    [(false, false, false, true)] = () => { /* do something */ },
    [(false, false, true, false)] = () => { /* do something else */ },
    [(false, false, true, true)] = SomeClassMethod,
    // and so on
};
```

Now you can invoke code from `if/else` block with single line:

```
methodTable[(check1, check2, check3, check4)].Invoke();
```

---

**EDIT**

If there is some combination of checkboxes you do not want to process you have to options:

Add empty handlers to `methodTable` like:

```
[(false, false, false, true)] = () => {}, // do nothing
```

Or (which is better for me) use `TryGetValue` method:

```
if (methodTable.TryGetValue((check1, check2, check3, check4), out var method))
    method.Invoke();
```

Comment: If OP goes with this solution, make sure to include all 16 different options in the dictionary, or he will need to check if the key exists as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use an enumeration :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication46
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        enum CheckBoxEnum
        {
            CHECKBOXNONE = 0,
            CHECKBOX1 = 1,
            CHECKBOX2 = 2,
            CHECKBOX3 = 4,
            CHECKBOX4 = 8,
        }

        List<CheckBox> checkboxes;
        CheckBoxEnum boxEnum = CheckBoxEnum.CHECKBOXNONE;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            checkboxes = new List<CheckBox>() { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4 };

            foreach (CheckBox box in checkboxes)
            {
                box.Click += new EventHandler(box_Click);
            }

            switch (boxEnum)
            {
                case CheckBoxEnum.CHECKBOX1 | CheckBoxEnum.CHECKBOX3 :
                    break;
            }





        }
        private void box_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox box = sender as CheckBox;
            if (box.Checked)
            {
                boxEnum |= (CheckBoxEnum)(1 << checkboxes.IndexOf(box));
            }
            else
            {
                boxEnum &= ~(CheckBoxEnum)(1 << checkboxes.IndexOf(box));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For 4 checkboxes you can do something like this:

Add them into array

```
bool[] checkboxes = { check1, check2, check3, check4 };
```

then select their 10 power by its indices, so you can use their `Sum` to get unique values for each one:

```
var selected = checkboxes
                     .Reverse() // reversing to get result with correct order
                     .Select((s, i) => new { IsChecked = s, Index = Math.Pow(10, i) })
                     .Where(w => w.IsChecked)
                     .Sum(s => s.Index);
```

so you will get `1100` for `true, true, false, false`, or `101` for `false, true, false, true`, etc.

and you can have `Dictionary<double, Action>` for all possibilities, like:

```
Dictionary<double, Action> methods = new Dictionary<double, Action>
{
    { 0000,  YourMethod },
    { 0001,  YourMethod1 },
    { 0010,  YourMethod2 },
    { 0011,  YourMethod3  },
    { 0100,  YourMethod4  },
    { 0101,  YourMethod5  },
    { 0110,  YourMethod6  },
    { 0111,  YourMethod7  },
    { 1000,  YourMethod8  },
    { 1001,  YourMethod9  },
    { 1010,  YourMethod10  },
    { 1011,  YourMethod11  },
    { 1100,  YourMethod12  },
    { 1101,  YourMethod13  },
    { 1110,  YourMethod14  },
    { 1111,  YourMethod15  },
};
```

and call it like this:

```
 methods[selected]();
```

Answer (score 2):

(*I know you already have an answer, consider this option as a possible alternative in another occasion*).

You can associate a specific Action with a Control or a collection of controls, then perform all the associated actions when it's required, triggering the actions in a sequence. A specific sequence, if required, as it is here.

For example, your **`createKeys()`** method has a higher priority when selected, **`createDocs()`** *one level* less, but it must be executed before the others when those are active too and so on.

So, using a *manager* class, you can associate all the actions (method calls) to the state of a Control, define the Action priority, then perform all the actions in one call when a conditon changes (a CheckBox is selected, a Button is clicked etc.).

Using the **`ActionManager`** class, you can associate Actions to Controls, add them to the class then call **`PerformActions()`** to execute all the active method:

```
ActionManager.Actions.AddRange(new[] {
    new ActionManager.ActionControl(() => CreateKeys(), this.chkCreateKeys, 1),
    new ActionManager.ActionControl(() => CreateDocs(), this.chkCreateDocs, 2),
    new ActionManager.ActionControl(() => AddKeys(), this.chkAddKeys, 3),
    new ActionManager.ActionControl(() => ReorderKeys(), this.chkReorderKeys, 4)
});
```

When needed, just call:

```
 ActionManager.PerformActions();
```

and all methods are executed.

This is how it performs, on a `CheckedChanged` event (could be a Button click or anything else):

[image: CheckBox Manager class]

**`ActionManager`** class:

```
public class ActionManager
{
    public static List<ActionControl> Actions { get; set; } = new List<ActionControl>();
    public static void PerformActions() {
        var sequence = Actions.Where(c => c.Control.Checked).OrderBy(a => a.ActionPriority);
        foreach (var action in sequence) {
           action.Action?.Invoke();
        }
    }
    public class ActionControl
    {
        public ActionControl(Action action, CheckBox control, int priority) {
            this.Action = action;
            this.Control = control;
            this.ActionPriority = priority;
        }
        public Action Action { get; }
        public CheckBox Control { get; }
        internal int ActionPriority { get; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We'll be using sets of numbers representing which checkboxes are set, so `{1, 3}` means `check1 && check3`.

If all the logic is completely separate, i.e. there is no connection between actions taken for `{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n}` and `{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n, x}` for any `a_1, ..., a_n` and `x`, then obviously you need to have `2^n` separate procedures for each combination. That means that either way we have to branch into `2^n` different code flows. So the question boils down to whether we can decide which set to use in a less code consuming way.

Obviously, you need to somehow wire up behaviour to different sets. That means that no matter what we do, under the assumption that we can have `2^n` completely unrelated procedures, one for each set, you still have to have at least `2^n` statements that will link a particular set to a particular procedure. So the short answer is no, even if you got rid of `if/else` statements, for example encoding the checks as sequences of bits and then mapping these sequences to procedures, you'd get rid of the logic here, but somewhere else in the code you'd have to have mappings like:

```
Dictionary<string, Action> logic = new Dictionary<int[], Action>();

logic["{1}"] = DoStuffFor1;
logic["{2}"] = DoStuffFor2;
...
logic["{N}"] = DoStuffForN;
logic["{1, 2}"] = DoStuffFor12;
logic["{1, 3}"] = DoStuffFor13;
...

var checkboxSet = Encode(check1, check2, ..., checkN); // Implementation of Encode should be obvious.
logic[checkboxSet].Invoke();
```

so still `2^n` statements. Thus, for a general case there's no way of decreasing the number of lines you write, but you might find a map of delegates more elegant than a swarm of `if/else` statements.

If, however, the logic for different sets of checkboxes is interconnected somehow, which will be the case in any reasonable real life application, you could probably collapse the `if` statements to shorten the code. But without more details about the actual logic of the program it's impossible to tell.

**EDIT:**

Actually, now that I come to think of it, you *could* have a very convoluted way of resolving a method name at runtime using reflection, and by using a naming convention for your methods so that the names for all handlers are nonambiguous (for example a method handling `{1, 42, 100}` would be named `DoStuffFor_1_42_100` etc.) you could fetch a method with name equivalent to the checked checkboxes and invoke it. It would still require you to write the `2^n` procedures, though. Also I think we can unanimously agree that it's a terrible idea to use reflection for this thing and rely on a naming convention for the code to work.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen You're right, the parentheses were a mistake, changed it to method groups.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Right again, changed to strings.