# Handle all checkbox events on a single method

Tags: c#, winforms

I found some similar questions but none of them on `C#` `Winforms`. I have many similar methods for different `Checkboxes` I have on my form, but now the number of checks is about to double and I'm looking for a simpler way of doing this.

Here's an example:

```
private void CheckPET_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckPET.Checked)
    {
        CheckAdicionarMaterial("PET");
    }
    else
    {
        if (Confirmacao())
            CheckRemoverMaterial("PET");
        else
            CheckPET.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

I have one of these for each `Checkbox`, and all of them follow the same pattern, so if I could have a method that handles all clicks I could do something like this:

```
private void GenericCheckbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Checkbox.Checked)
    {
        CheckAdicionarMaterial(Checkbox.Text);//The text of the boxes is always the string I want to pass here.
    }
    else
    {
        if (Confirmacao())
            CheckRemoverMaterial(Checkbox.Text);
        else
            Checkbox.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Have all the CheckBoxes use the same method, and then use the "sender" to know which CheckBox was being clicked.  Generally, CheckChanged is more appropriate than Click.

Comment: I use click to give the user a chance to go back after he reads what the click does. If it's already checked a click will delete the entries

Comment: I understand directing all of them to the same method but how do I use the sender as you suggested?

Comment: You cast it to a CheckBox, then you can examine the Name or Tag or Text property.

Comment: You can associate a Control with an Action. Cast sender to CheckBox (`var chkBox = sender as CheckBox;`) in the event handler and use [code similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56938597/7444103) to trigger a specific action linked to a specific control.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to do it by casting `sender` to a CheckBox variable, and then using the variable as suggested by LarsTech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly - binding a single function as an event handler for several checkboxes?

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CheckBox checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
   if (checkbox == null) return;
   if (checkbox.Checked)
   {
     CheckAdicionarMaterial(checkbox.Text);//The text of the boxes is always the string I want to pass here.
   }else
   {
     if (Confirmacao("Desmarcar removerá todas ocorrências do material. Continuar?"))
       CheckRemoverMaterial(checkbox.Text);
     else
         checkbox.Checked = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, but check for null here?

Comment: Just a rule of good tone - after each soft conversion of "as" - to check the result to null. If, for example, this event handler func will attached to a radiobutton, then when you click on it, there will be radibutton in the sender parameter. And the result of this conversion will be null