# Saving state of multiple checkboxes using lists

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making application that stores data that users input through form. Since i have quite a few checkboxes and form stretches on multiple pages. I want to save state of these checkboxes so when i go to next page and come back, previously checked checkboxes should be checkedagain.
I am trying to accomplish this by using `List<CheckBox>` and `bool[]`. But it just doesnt work for some reason. I dont know what i am missing.

```
public void Ucitavanje34(bool[] Lista,List<CheckBox> check )
    {
        foreach (CheckBox ajtem in check)
        {
            int i = 0;
            if (ajtem.Checked==true)
            {
                Lista[i] = true;
                ++i;
            }
            else
            {
                Lista[i]= false;
                ++i;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,Checkboxstrana3,boolarray ));            
    }

public void Ucitavanje43(bool[] Lista, List<CheckBox> check)
    {
        foreach (bool ajtem in Lista)
        {
            int i = 0;
            if (ajtem == true)
            {
                check[i].Checked = true;
                ++i;
            }
            else
            {
                check[i].Checked = false;
                ++i;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,Stanje));
    }
```

I know i can do this manually(1by1) but it is to cumbersome.

The output i get is just silly and i dont know what i am doing wrong .

Comment: Use a dictionary?

Comment: This is a general programming error which could have been fixed by debugging.

Comment: [Is there a more elegant way to write logic for multiple checkboxes being checked other than multiple if statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56938597/7444103). See also the accepted answer for a simplified method, which may works if you have only a few, static, checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting `i` to zero for each check box. It would probably be better to use a single for loop and use `i` for the index on both the `List` and the `bool[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the for loop
you are doing int i=0; inside forloop. This will always fetch the first element from list.

```
public void Ucitavanje34(bool[] Lista,List<CheckBox> check )
{
   int i = 0; //this line
   foreach (CheckBox ajtem in check)
   {          
      Lista[i] = ajtem.Checked;
      ++i;      
   }
   MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,Checkboxstrana3,boolarray ));            
}
```

Comment: You just suggested use `Dictionary` in comment. I believe this is great approach to store the state but I don't how to store `Checkbox` as a key (Key should be unique)

Comment: you can use the control name as key. Dictionary<string,bool>

Comment: @CodeNameJack ok i fixed that but it still doesnt work.I will try with dictionary.

Comment: additionaly you don't need that if else part. You can just assign

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already pointed out your problem, I just wanted to provied a different approach because your task is a good example where you can benefit from using LINQ.

```
bool[] Lista = check.Select(x => x.IsChecked).ToArray();
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8 if you're interested in that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Dictionary<string, bool> Save(params CheckBox[] check)
{
    Dictionary<string, bool> result = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    foreach (CheckBox item in check)
        result.Add(item.Name, item.Checked);

    return result;
}

public void Apply(Dictionary<string, bool> savedResults)
{
    foreach (var item in savedResults)
    {
        var check = this.Controls[item.Key];
        // var check = this.Controls.Find(item.Key, true).FirstOrDefault();  //easier way to find checkboxes
        if(check != null && check.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox")
        {
            ((CheckBox)check).Checked = item.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**How to call it:**

```
result = Save(checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4);
```

Now, save the `result` everywhere you want.

**How to use it:**

```
Dictionary<string, bool> result = ... // Load from somewhere
Apply(result);
```