# How to select one Button at a time in a Button Group in .NET Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, button, boolean, do-while

I have made a custom `button control` and want it to behave like `RadioButtons` in a group. The button will be placed in a group or collection of its type on the same `container` or `panel` (button dragged_dropped onto the container). When i click any of these buttons, i need the following to happen:

1. Change the `BackColor` of the clicked button to a predefined color: `Color.Cycan;`
2. Set the checked state of the clicked button from `false` to `true`
3. Ensure that all other buttons of the same type on the same panel/container are set to their default settings which are:
   `BackColor = Color.Gray;`
   `checked = false;`

**I have tried the below `code` but i am obtaining this result:**

1. The `BackColor` of the clicked button is changing successfully to `Color.Cycan;`
2. The default `BackColor` of all other buttons of the same type on the same container is being set to default successfully: `Color.Gray;`
3. But the `checked state` of the clicked button is not changing to `true.` It remains `false.`

I have attached the code i have tried, below:

What could be the issue or where am i missing the point?

This is a `Winform / Windows Forms` button control and i am programming in `C#.`

I do not want to use a radio button for this because i have custom designed `MyButton`.

Thank you.

> ***THIS IS THE CODE I HAVE TRIED:***

***// Calling 'ClickedButton();' on click event.***

```
private bool checked = false;
private void ClickedButton()
{

do(

BackColor = Color.Cycan;
checked = true;

if(Parent == null)
break;

foreach(MyButton button in Parent.Controls.OfType<MyButton>())
{

if(button == this) { continue }

else{

BackColor = Color.Gray;
checked = false;
}
}

)
while(false)
}
```

Comment: Where is checked variable defined?

Comment: It is defined in the same class as the function. I have edited the code to reflect this. I had bad-formatted the code so StackOverflow couldn't show the variable. I have edited it to reflect the variable.

Comment: See the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56938597/7444103). It defines the behavior of some controls, related to each other, using `Action()`s.

Comment: What is the role of the `do...while` here? Doesn't make sense. The foreach...next is enough and will do the job. Remove the `do..while` block and give it a try.

Comment: @JQSOFT: Removing the ```do..while``` loop does not solve the problem. I want the checked state of the clicked button to be set to ```true``` and set all other buttons checked state to ```false```. Be sure enough to include tested code in your response, i may be missing something here. I resorted to use the ```do while loop``` in an attempt to change the ```boolean``` state of the buttons.

Comment: How did you managed to do this? `private bool` **checked** `= false;` Anyways, @Hotkey gave you a beautiful solution. Good luck.

Comment: @JQSOFT: Most likely your advice to remove the ```do...while``` loop was just exactly like what we see in the solution provided by @Hotkey. I was missing the point. I got it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Most welcome mate. At your disposal anytime.

Comment: Have you ever noticed `Appearance` property of `RadioButton` can be set to `Button` and `FlatStyle` can be set to `Flat` and `FlatAppearance` have propertied for setting `MouseOverBackColor` and `CheckedBackColor`? You can satisfy the requirement without any custom control. Also a `ToolStrip` will be a really good option for a vertical navigation menu. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36252030/3110834).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about use this method?

```cs
private bool isSelected = false;

private Color activeColor = Color.FromArgb(117, 117, 117);
private Color defaultColor = Color.FromArgb(66, 66, 66);

private void ClickedButton()
{
    foreach (Control parentControl in Parent.Controls)
    {
        if (parentControl is MyButton parentButton)
        {
            parentButton.isSelected = false;
            parentButton.BackColor = parentButton.isSelected ? parentButton.activeColor : parentButton.defaultColor;
        }
    }

    this.isSelected = true;
    this.BackColor = isSelected ? activeColor : defaultColor;
}
```

It works like this.

[image: buttonTest]

Comment: I appreciate your solution. Not only does it work but the code is much cleaner and faster than iterating inside a ```do...while``` loop. I tested your solution and it generates the desired result.